# Rewrite url using regex matchcollection in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create an adapter/engine to rewrite url using regex match collection in C# but i am stuck.

Sample Old url http://www.example.com/news/index.aspx?city=nairobi&country=kenya

Sample New url http://www.example.com/news/nairobi/kenya

The adapter should take data from new url and rewrite as old url.

What is have tried so far in global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    HttpContext incoming = HttpContext.Current;
    string city;
    string country;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches;
    matches = GetMatches("/news/(\\w+)/(\\w+)");

    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        city = matches[0].Groups[1].ToString();
        country = matches[1].Groups[1].ToString();
        incoming.RewritePath("../news/index.aspx?city=" + city + "&country=" + country);
        return;
    }
}
```

How can i achieve the desired results?

Comment: the `\d+` mean 1 or more **digits**. I think you are looking for `\w+`: one ore more "word" characters

Comment: You can try using verbal expressions: https://dev.to/bachnxhedspi/verbalexpressions---regularexpression-made-easy-27a8

Comment: You should rephrase the question and show what you want to achieve. Both Michał Turczyn and Mario Vázquez misunderstood your question: they think you want a regex to extract the data from the old url. But what you are actually doing is writing an adapter that takes data from the new url and rewrite it as the old url. This is not clear in your question.

Comment: I have edited the questions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`/news/.+[?]city=(.+)&country=(.+)`

Getting the city in group 1 and the country in group 2.

Tested with this usefull online tool:
http://regexstorm.net/tester for .NET

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string old_url = @"http://www.example.com/news/index.aspx?city=nairobi&country=kenya";

string new_url = Regex.Replace(old_url, @"news\/.+city=([^&]+).+country=([^&]+)",@"news/$1/$2");
```